# elixir script is not printing output to the console

Tags: elixir

I'm an elixir newbie and novice. I'm working through the [joy of elixir](https://joyofelixir.com/5-funky-functions).

I've created below directory structure `joy-of-elixir/5-funky-functions` and created a file called `hello.exs`.

[image]

The contents of `hello.exs` is below -

```
greeting = fn (name, gender, age) ->
         "Hello #{name} I see you're #{gender} and of age #{age}"
         end

greeting.("Raj", "Male", 33)

greeting2 = fn (place) -> "Hello #{place}" end

greeting2.("Tgode")
greeting2.("name")
```

I'm trying to execute the script using command `elixir 5-funky-functions/hello.exs` but I neither get anything in the output nor any error.

[image]

I think I'm missing something how can I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike a regular elixir program (`.exs` script or regular `.ex` file), IEx prints the value of every evaluated line (which is what [REPLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) do).

Your code is just creating these strings, but it is not using them for anything.

In a program, you would need to explicitly declare yourself when and how you want to print something. You could use either:

- [`IO.puts/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#puts/1) if you want to print the content of a string (works with some other types as well), e.g. `"Hello\tworld"` just gets printed as `Hello   world`
- [`IO.inspect/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#inspect/1) if you want to print the representation of any Elixir value, e.g. `"Hello\tWorld"` gets printed as `"Hello\tWorld"`

`IO.inspect/1` is what IEx is doing, but in practice it is mostly being used for debugging. Most scripts that need to output some text would rely on `IO.puts/1`.

Example:

```elixir
fn (place) -> IO.puts("Hello #{place}") end
```